# Removing events from HTML tag (ondrag) programmatically with @if statements

Tags: html, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am building an interactive Blazor Server UI where you can drag and drop cards into different orders. The UI is working fine, but I want to make it switchable so that I can enter and leave "sort mode." When not in sort mode, I thought it may be best to remove the ondrag events completely from the app to make it more optimized.

Here is the functioning code:

```
<div class="row" ondragover="event.preventDefault();">
    @foreach (var photo in files)
    {
        <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-4" 
             draggable="true" //This doesn't seem to be settable by a bool
             @key="photo.Id" 
             tabindex="1"
             @ondragstart="@(()=> StartDrag(photo))"
             @ondragover="@(()=> DragOver(photo))">
               <div class="card">Card contents here</div>
        </div>
     }
</div>
```

I want to remove the `ondragover`, `@ondragstart="@(()=> StartDrag(photo))"`, and `@ondragover="@(()=> DragOver(photo))"` sections

My first thought was to wrap each opening `<div>` in an if/else and have two versions, one with the additional code and one without, but even though there are two opening `<div>`s in an if/else, the compiler gives an error saying there's an opening div without a closing.

```
@if (isSortOn)
{
<div class="row" ondragover="event.preventDefault();"> // ERROR - No closing </div>
}
else
{
<div> class="row">
}
     [...OTHER STUFF HERE...]
</div>  // This should be the closing div
```

Since that didn't work, I tried to remove the methods programmatically within the `<div>` with if/else, but I got errors similar to below:

```
<div class="row" @(isSortOn ? ondragover="event.preventDefault();" : "")> 
      //ERROR- can't do @codeblock inside tag

<div class="row" ondragover=@(isSortOn ? "event.preventDefault();" : "")> 
      //ERROR- sees event as string and not proper event/
```

How can I remove this functionality and use if/else to control these tags?

**EDIT/CLARIFICATION:** A user had suggested setting `draggable="@isSortOn"` but that doesn't seem to work. First, the flag doesn't appear to actually be necessary for the code to function. Second, for some reason if I set it to a bool toggling the bool doesn't actually toggle the behavior (not sure why). Third, if I set `draggable="false"` in the card's outer `<div>` and inner `<img>` tags, I can disable dragging. However, if you highlight some text, you can then drag things around and cause the events to re-fire. Not sure exactly how the `draggable` property works, but it seems very fragile.

Comment: You will spend more resources removing and adding the drag events. Your best bet is to only apply them when sort mode is activated, and then just have an on/off variable to prevent actions.

Comment: A sneaky way is to use the `@attributes=SomeDictionary` and modify the dictionary it uses.

Comment: @BrianParker Sorry for the delay, but I'm not sure the syntax in the C# side to pull this off. I tried adding a `Dictionary<string,object>` with the key/value pair, but I'm not sure what to enter for the value to trigger a method call. For example with `@onclick` if I make the entry `SomeDictionary.Add("onclick", CallMethodHere()` then it will compile, and run, but when I go to display the component it doesn't display properly. I tried a lambda and it won't compile. I can, however, remove the entry with an `if` as you suggested, and it works. I just don't know the syntax to do the method call.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you're not running into something funky with Visual Studio? I'm able to run your second example code just fine with .NET 6 and Visual Studio 2022.

```
// Index.razor

<div class="row" @(isSortOn ? onclick="window.alert('hello')" : string.Empty)>
    Hello
</div>

@code {
    public bool isSortOn { get; set; } = true;  
}
```

Comment: I'm in .NET5, VS2019. I get the following error: `Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': '@(isSortOn' is not a valid attribute name [.......]`

Comment: Might be worth a shot to make sure you've got the experimental (in 2019) Razor language features enabled or even give VS2022 a shot. - https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/new-experimental-razor-editor-for-visual-studio/

Comment: sorry for the delay, but I tried the experimental features and it still didn't work. Once I move to .NET 6, I'll check back and let you know if it worked. Thanks!